# Classes versus parameterized instances

Tags: python, oop, class, design-patterns, architecture

Let's say I have a class hierarchy. I could theoretically maintain its functionality with a single class, by providing extra parameters to the instances. Here's an example (super-contrived, but I wanted to keep it simple):

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
  def f(self, x):
    raise NotImplemented # needs to be defined in subclass

class Mult(Base)
  def f(self, x):
    return self.a * x

class Add(Base):
  def f(self, x):
    return self.a + x

m = Mult(5)
a = Add(7)
m.f(10)
a.f(20)
```

The above code can be refactored as:

```
class Compute:
  def __init__(self, a, func):
    self.a = a
    self.func = func
  def f(self, x)
    return self.func(self.a, x)

m = Compute(5, operator.mult)
a = Compute(7, operator.add)
```

I understand that for this silly example, it makes no difference. So please don't think about it except to understand my point.

I want to know what factors I should think about when making this choice for the variety of situations I  encounter in real life? In other words, what are the pros / cons of using classes versus parameterized instances?

Comment: Could you give some details of what you're trying to do IRL? Sounds like you want your class to be able to execute arbitrary functions, but have some pre-defined as well. IMO this should be a single class with the pre-defined functions stored in a dict.

Comment: @poorsod I need represent a great variety of business rules, which have a lot of overlap. I wonder whether I should create a class hierarchy, or simply create instances that are instantiated with the right functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you supply the client code with canned ways of doing a fixed set of operations. It’s easy to multiply, but if you want to divide instead, well, tough luck.

In the second example, you push implementation details up to the client. You now have an entire *operation-agnostic computation framework*. This requires more knowledge in the client code.

So, what really differs is the level of abstraction—how knowledgeable you want your client to be. If it is important for the client that `operator.mult` be used, not some other logic (like, XML-RPC to a multiplication server), the second option seems appropriate. If the client knows better than you what to do with the two numbers, and you want to provide only a framework (a wrapper of sorts), the second option is better. If you just want to let people add and multiply stuff, the first option is better.

Comment: Thx, this is an interesting observation. I do think though that even if I don't put any knowledge into the client, I might still follow the second option: I can just pre-instantiate objects `m` and `a`, so that as far as the client is concerned there's just a few variants to choose from with no transparency.

Comment: @max The “client” I’m talking about is whatever instantiates your class(es). If you do this privately, the client is your own code co-located with the class definition(s). In that case, the choice is less important (just an internal implementation detail), but the same considerations still apply.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the classes do. In your example the logic in the classes it so minimal it is obvious you've just supplied wrappers for methods as classes. and it makes more sense to have the compute class.

In real life situations you should ask yourself how [cohesive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) are the different functions you want to group together. Though single responsibility is important you don't need to take that ad absurdum

Comment: In my case, I feel `Compute(5, operator.mult)` is more elegant than `Mult(5)`, since the former treats all parameters in a uniform way, while the latter creates a mess by splitting what is really two parameters into two entirely different syntactic structures. But I'm afraid taking this argument too far would lead me to avoid classes entirely, and pass everything as parameters. At what point should I stop?

Comment: When the class gets starts to do too many unrelated things. Bob Martin defined the Single Responsibility principle as a "Class should have one reason to change".  Anyway you can always ask here if you have some specific case :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on whether you'll have all the information about transformations (?) you'll do on the object available at construction time.  If you don't, you'd have trouble calling the more complicated constructor.

Further, leaving the option open to do things to the "basic" object, before committing it down a certain path is often helpful, even if not apparent when initially designing the classes.

In general, I've found that creating a constructor with the *minimum required parameters* and implementing any other functionality via methods to be the best solution.

In the spirit of random examples, consider:

**Parameterized Constructor**

```
class Image:
    # Some implementation

class Text:
    def __init__(self, image, whitelistChars):
        # This uses OCR to extract the text from an image then filters out 
        #   non-whitelisted characters
        #
        # image is an Image
        # whitelistChars is an interable containing characters that should 
        #   not be filtered out

im = Image('scan.tif')
t = Text(im, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ134567890');
```

**Basic Constructor**

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self, image):
        # This uses OCR to extract the text from an image
        #
        # image is an Image


    def filter(self, whitelistChars):
        # This filters out non-whitelisted characters
        #
        # whitelistChars is an interable containing characters that should 
        #   not be filtered out

im = Image('scan.tif')
t = Text(im)
# <-- Are you interested in doing anything to the Text object t here?
t.filter('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ134567890')
```

In the "Basic Constructor" implementation, you have the option to use the `Text` object `t` prior to stripping the non-whitelisted characters.  Maybe this is useful?  Maybe more importantly, *maybe this will be useful in the future?*

If you can confidently say, "No", it's not useful and never will be then I think the "Parametrized Constructor" is fine.  If anything, it eliminates the need for the extra `filter` call.

But leaving open the option to manipulate `t`, or even just inspect it, prior to transforming it (in this case filter the text), is often helpful if you hope to reuse the code.

(My $0.02)

Comment: I agree with your comments, but you are analyzing a different choice than the one I'm facing. I am choosing between parameterized methods (whether `__init__` or another one doesn't really matter much) vs a class hierarchy (where the parameters are predefined for each class). For you, the choice against a class hierarchy is already made, and you're deciding whether parameters belong in the `__init__` method or other methods.